# Calculate total value along sequence based on fix percentage and sequence

Tags: math, sequence, percentage

So I know how to do this using a function on any given programming language but I wonder how to do it with a formula. This is to calculate the price of a item in a game. The item cost initially 200 but once the user buys it, its price gets incremented a 20% so now cost 240 and it will cost 288 the very next time as it is a 20% increment from the last price. What if I want to calculate the price based on the sequence, lets say the item is on level 12 (has been bought or upgraded 11 times), what is the formula to calculate the price without using a loop (storing the previous value) but based only on the current level (12), the base price (200) and the fix percentage (20%)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const price = (1+percent)**(level-1) * initialPrice
```

Basic compound interest formula :-)

(`**` is the power operator)

Comment: what the "**" means on your formula?

Comment: it works if the percentage is set as 0.2 rather than 20. Thanks!
Example for the record: var $price = Math.pow(1+(20/100),7-1) * 200; //where 7 is the level ,20 the percentage and 200 the original price